# Go interface: Cannot assign value to unexported field

Tags: go

I try to mock some struct for unit testing and I use following [site](https://blog.codecentric.de/2019/07/gomock-vs-testify/#testifymock)

I wrote following:

**Doer**

```
package user

import "errors"

type Doer interface {
    Do(int, string) error
}

type DoerImp struct {

}

func (d *DoerImp)Do(val int, str string) error{
    if val == 3{
        return errors.New("Some error")
    }
    return nil
}
```

**User**

```
package user

type User struct {
    doer Doer
}

func (u *User) UseDoer() {
    u.doer.Do(1, "abc")
}
```

And from the main I want to run this code:

```
c := &user.DoerImp{}
u := user.User{c}
u.UseDoer()
```

However I get an error: `Cannot assign value to unexported field 'doer'`

What I'm doing wrong?
my `c` value has `Doer` interface signature

Comment: Change `doer Doer` field to `Doer Doer`. **Unexported** fields, those that start with a lower case letter, can be set and read only inside the package in which they were declared. Note that, while it's possible to elide the field name in the composite literal, as you're doing with `user.User{c}`, the rule mentioned above still applies.

Comment: Going through the complete [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) might help establish the language fundamentals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error indicates that `doer` is an unexported field and thus inaccessible from another package.

Depending on whether you want it to be accessible you can either change it's declaration to be exported:

```golang
package user

type User struct {
    Doer Doer
}

func (u *User) UseDoer() {
    u.Doer.Do(1, "abc")
}
```

---

Or you can use something similar to a constructor:

```golang
package user

func New(doer Doer) *User {
    return &User{doer}
}

type User struct {
    doer Doer
}

func (u *User) UseDoer() {
    u.doer.Do(1, "abc")
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```golang
u := user.New{&user.DoerImp{}}
u.UseDoer()
```